# Convergence of R-squared and Predicted R-squared

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared

We know for a fact that R-squared would reach 1 when more X's are added to the model. Many have suggested the use of Predicted R-squared as a measure of predictive power, and we know that its value gets smaller as the number of X's increases. My question is, what is the limit of predicted R-squared as p (the number of predictors) approaches infinity?

As for the case of R-squared, we know its limit as p approaches infinity is 1, but is there an analytical proof for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi: predicted R squared has no limit as long as it doesn't use the data that the model was estimated from.  as far as the other proof, it's probably the same proof ( I don't know where it is ) that any function can be approximated by a polynomial with enough powers. see the well  neural network paper  by hornik et al ( forget the name. early 90's )  which  shows that any function can be approximated by a neural network with enough nodes. not sure if there's a proof in there  but the concept is similar.

Comment: How exactly do you defined predicted R-squared? Also, here is the paper mentioned by mlofton: Hornik, Stinchcombe & White ["Multilayer feedforward networks are universal approximators"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893608089900208) (1989).

Comment: @mlofton If we conceive of "predicted $R^2$" as the $R^2$ of the fit of an independent sample using the current parameter estimates, then provided the parameter estimation procedure is asymptotically consistent, the predicted $R^2$ ought to converge to the population $R^2$ as the two sample sizes (data size and future sample size) grow arbitrarily large.  This would essentially be a law of large numbers.

Comment: @whuber: I see what you're saying and there's a whole literature on this that I looked at a while back. My take was that the Diebold-Mariano test framework was just for the reason that using parameters estimated based on a training sample and then generating the predictions using those estimates out of sample was kind of "independent" of the training sample. Let me see if I can track down the paper. I have it somewhere. I shall return. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @whuber: If you or anyone else can be bothered, this paper introduced  the D-M test in econometrics  which is or atleast was quite popular at one point. If what you're saying is true, then it seems to be that this test would be redundant in that one could just use the in sample $R^2$, since  it  converges to the predicted $R^2$. My point is that, if what you're saying is true, then it would make the DM-stat not very helpful. So,  my current understanding is that there is not convergence but I could be wrong. It's appreciated. https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper68/pa.dm.pdf

Comment: @Richard Hardy: My definition of predicted $R^2$ would be the same as in the sample one except it's compares predictions to out-of sample instead of fitted values to in-sample.  Appreciate if you could possibly take a look at D-M paper because I went through a lot of stuff with that and variants but maybe whuber is correct ? Or D-M is doing something else then what I think it's doing. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton I overlooked one important subtlety--or rather, made an implicit assumption about it: it's not enough to consider what happens as "the number of predictors goes to infinity," because one must also consider what simultaneously happens to the number of *observations.*  Different answers will arise depending on the mechanisms of augmenting observations and augmenting predictors.

Comment: @whuber: absolutely. the case where there is an increasing number of observations is what the diebold-mariano test deals with. hopefully, the OP is reading this because my answer also was not clear on this. So, to the OP: If the number of observations is increasing, then, no, the two don't converge. if the number of observations is not increasing ( but this wouldn't make that much practical sense because, when predicting, you're getting new observations ), then I think that whuber is correct in that you would get convergence due to CLT.

Comment: @cereal: just to be clear, I re-read your question and it's not clear if the number of observations is increasing as you predict so whuber could be correct. your question seems pretty theoretically based ( rather than practitioner based ) so maybe they don't increase. All the best and thanks for question because I learned a lot from this discussion.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the comments. My definition of predicted R-square is the one based on out-of-sample. In here, predicted R-square  = 1 - PRESS/SST(i). I want to check where R-square and predicted R-square will converge to assuming the number of observations (n) is fixed, and the number of predictors (p) is increasing. I will read on the paper you guys provided and comment back on this thread. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi: If the number of observations is fixed, then I don't think the D-M paper is exactly relevant but it would be useful for you to read it anyway to see what's going on there. What I don't understand is, if the number of observations is fixed, then  what's the difference between estimation and prediction ? In the case of a fixed # of observations, predictions are just the fitted values and therefore "part of" the estimation process. Anyway, I probably can't say more about this and I'm glad it was useful to you. Thanks to whuber for his interesting comment which could be correct for your case.

Comment: @mlofton what I'm trying to see is for a fixed n, we know R^2 would converge to 1 as the number of predictors increases. In the case of the predicted R-square, the PRESS statistic (leave-one-out sum of squared error) increases as the number of predictors increases, and sometimes go to a negative value. I want to understand what happens in that case.

Comment: @cereal: are you doing the predictions on the same data that you estimated the model ( the one with increased predictors ? ) with ? That's what I'm not clear on. Thanks.